# Poor contrast on the “How to Ask” widgets

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

On Meta, the “How to Ask” and other rectangular widgets on the right of the screen that appear when you ask a question are very dark islands in an almost-white page. I don't like it, but it may just be a matter of personal preference.

On the main site, I would really like better contrast between the text and the background of these widgets.

Comment: u got a link to the 'how to ask' page?

Comment: @Tshepang: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask , the `<div class="module newuser">` bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [latest design update](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/site-design-updates)):

- Main site

  [image: main — Similar Questions]
- Meta

  [image: meta — How to Ask]

Works for me.