# Site Design Updates

Tags: discussion, design

**A major design update is now live!**

Most of the changes are not visible; these tweaks go along with recent updates that were made to Stack Overflow:

- We are moving the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future.
- We are updating the graphics to SVG for retina support.
- We've fixed a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network.

Visually it should "feel" the same as the old site with slight layout adjustments.

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. If you see any new ones, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!

Comment: There is too much empty space between questions to my taste. It comes from avatars.

Comment: Feels weird, probably that I'm not used to it.

Comment: The question and answer scores looks different—smaller maybe? Probably intentional, I guess?

Comment: @kurtis-beavers Any word on fixing the regressions?

Comment: @Mikel we just pushed a few changes. Most of the issues listed below have been resolved. There are a few other things that we are still working on.

Comment: Out of curiosity. Have colors for links vs. visited links been swapped? E.g. for *questions* listing.

Answer (score 20):

Let me go through [previously reported issues](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design+-status-completed?sort=newest):

- [Captcha Image Nominations](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118/captcha-image-nominations) — NO, we still have the boring captcha image
- [404 Image Nominations](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/404-image-nominations) — NO, we still have the boring 404 image
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
  [Bolder question title font](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/bolder-question-title-font) — there've been several changes since then, at least to the site and perhaps to my perception. I'm ok with the page titles now, but **the titles on `/questions` are not visible enough**. They could stand being several points bigger, and perhaps bolder.
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
  [Poor contrast on the “How to Ask” widgets](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/413/poor-contrast-on-the-how-to-ask-widgets) — YES (actually from an earlier redesign IIRC)
- [Favourite tagged questions: highlight colors, too bright?..](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/favourite-tagged-questions-highlight-colors-too-bright) — ? The contrast is enough for me.
- [Error image nominations](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/error-image-nominations) — NO, we still have the boring error image
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
  [Can the font in the badges section be changed?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/761/can-the-font-in-the-badges-section-be-changed) — ?
- [Better question title font](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/800/better-question-title-font) — REGRESSION! **This serif font looks weird for titles that often contain bits of code**.
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
  [Code inside spoiler markup is not hidden](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/890/code-inside-spoiler-markup-is-not-hidden) — PARTIALLY. Code in spoilers is now hidden, but showing a different background.
  [image: code in spoiler]
- [Links colours are not distinctive enough](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/links-colours-are-not-distinctive-enough) — PARTIALLY. The link colors have changed, and I think they're now further from non-links, but **visited links and non-visited links are hard to tell apart**. The same problem occurs [on beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251473/new-beta-style-is-much-harder-on-my-eyes-looking-for-css-overrides-to-fix).
- [Font too small for code sections in headlines](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3187/font-too-small-for-code-sections-in-headlines) — NO, still exactly like before
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
  [Increase the contrast of 'similar questions' pane on unix stackexchange](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/increase-the-contrast-of-similar-questions-pane-on-unix-stackexchange) — YES!

One more important point, which I'm sure I've reported on meta before but I can't find now: **double quotes `"` in titles** are rewritten to their slanted versions `“…”`. This is highly inappropriate on a site where [quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quoting) is an important matter. Double quotes in titles are often the ASCII character (U+0022 QUOTATION MARK) in a bit of Unix shell syntax, and showing different characters gives the impression that what is written is not shell syntax. We can use the typographically pleasant U+201C and U+201D when we want. Please leave U+0022 alone when we mean it.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Here are a couple notes: I'll look into changing the captcha, error, and 404 pages. The text in the badges is now larger. The highlight color in the Favorite tagged questions has been dulled a bit. The question title font is still Liberation Serif. Will fix code spoiler background color on Meta.

Comment: +1 for the question titles. If you are not on a retina screen, they are painfully (literally) small...

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Thanks for the prompt reaction! Note that the spoiler issue was on main, not on meta.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers - could you please look at the issue of turning "curlies" back into straight quotation marks? It's weird as Hades: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191827/alias-g-1-what-does-it-do

Comment: @DeerHunter I'll look into it. I'm pretty sure it's a global issue and doesn't have anything to do with the recent site updates.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers It is a multi-site issue, but one that can't be solved globally. On sites with “human” content only, turning `"stuff"` into `“stuff”` is sensible. On sites like [unix.se] with bits of programs meant for computers, `"stuff"` is not at all the same thing as `“stuff”`.

Comment: @Gilles I understand, you should be able to use either dumb or smart quotes when you need them. This issue isn't related to the recent front end updates. I did a search through the meta bug reports but couldn't find anything on this. I'm going to pull someone else in to help out with this. There is time scheduled for bug fixes within the next week.

Comment: We looked at the quotes on the last several hundred posts. While *a few* would be more correct without fancy quotes, the vast majority are correct and would be negatively impacted by such a change. Given that, we want to stick with the net-positive of replacing the quotes globally.

Comment: @NickCraver You're reasoning as if the situation was symmetric, but it isn't, both because we don't get a choice and because one is a matter of aesthetics while the other is a matter of correctness. If a title would be improved by using typographic quotes, I can force them by using the appropriate characters. If a title is incorrect due to being displayed in typographic quotes, there's nothing I can do.

Comment: @NickCraver - this decision (to stick to fancy quotes) does Unix and Linux (and, incidentally, Server Fault and SO) a great disservice. Tons and tons of noobs coming in from Google would be better off with working recipes.

Comment: @NickCraver On Unix & Linux the technical (not aesthetic) aspect should matter the most. Aside from that I feel offended when any site, text editor or whatever "knows better" what **I** want to write. If I cannot even make it stop, this is rude and haughty.

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Odd `<a href>` remnant above the banner on Meta:

[image: Wayward clickable pixel]

Comment: Good catch. This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed. I don't see it, do you still see it Jason?

Comment: @terdon Yep, done :)

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please add `background-color: white` or make your layout working with dark window backgrounds.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The heading font is inconsistent with the rest of the page, and is harder to read for me.

Comment: The heading font is the same font as it was before the site conversion. We can look into a new one.

Comment: It used to be 18px, but now it's 16.  It's now too small, at least on Firefox Linux with whichever font I'm actually getting (Liberation Serif?).

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The question titles in the side bar for Sections "*Featured on Meta*", "*Hot Meta Posts*", "*Linked*" and "*Related*" are harder to read than before. It is now using `font-family: 'Liberation Serif', Georgia, Times, serif;` and `font-size: 12px;`.

The "*Hot Network Questions*" doesn't seem to have changed and is more readable. It is using `font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;` and `font-size: 12px;`.

The sans-serif fonts seem more readable. In addition, the serif fonts used here feel smaller. As far as I know, distinct fonts don't necessarily have the same visual size when used with an equivalent point size, so the same presumably applies to px sizes. (In fact, after zooming in an "o" in the new serif font at 12px is 6-pixel tall, whereas it is 7-pixel tall with the sans-serif font.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bruno. This will be fixed in the next production server build.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When editing favourite/ignored tags from the front page, the <kbd>Add</kbd> button is hidden because it protrudes beyond the right column (at least on FF ESR 31.5.3):

[image: layout bug: add button not visible]

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a dot pattern in the background.  I don't like that. :(

Comment: Downvote because you like the dots, or downvote because you're not seeing them?

Comment: There was a dot pattern in the background in the last version of the site.

Answer (score 0):

The links below questions break alignment when there are pending edits and (or?) close votes:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @terdon. This is a global bug that's been reported on meta.stackexchange.com. It should be resolved soon.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers yes, I thought I'd seen it reported somewhere. Great work overall though, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't happen with just pending edits and close votes, you also need the mod link.

Answer (score 0):

A minor cosmetic CSS thing.

When zooming out – I usually have zoom set to something between 65% and 90% – for some zoom levels one get a scroll-bar in the main menu.

It almost looks as if there is some disabled extra menu thing.

[image: Scrollbar in menubar]

(*Rightmost scroll-bar arrows*)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is new or not (which would indicate it is not that important either) but the Meta U&L logo in the side bar is blurry:

- firefox 37.0

  [image: blurry icon]
- It looks much better on chromium 31.0.1650.63. It's still a little blurry but not enough to really make it an issue:

  [image]
- Same goes for opera 12.16

  [image]

All screenshots were taken from a system running 64bit Debian.

Comment: Hmm. I can't reproduce this. Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers firefox 37.0 on 64bit Debian. It looks OK in chrome and opera, see updated answer.